# How to do this with SherlockFragments?

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, fragment

I am trying to transform an app using fragments into Sherlock and came accross this statement.
But I cannot find any implementation of show in Sherlock.

How can I do this in Sherlock?

```
fragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(),"dialog");
```

and this:

```
fragment.dismissAllowingStateLoss();
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've probably solved this by now, but for anyone who stumbles upon this thread: you just need to inherit Sherlock counterparts of Activity and Fragment, i.e: SherlockFragmentActivity and SherlockDialogFragment.

Once you do that, you'll have both of those methods available.

Comment: Thank you . in fact I used some kind of workaround - but your solution is better :-)

Comment: Glad that I could help after such a long time ;)